# Standard way to convert a string to a duration?

Tags: python, duration, timedelta

Is there a standard way (e.g. a function in the standard library or something close to it) to enter a duration or time delta as a string?

For example I would like to be able to enter something like `20m` or `01:23:14` and get for example a `datetime.timedelta`. (Those are just examples on top of my head, it doesn't need to handle those specific strings).

It wouldn't be too hard to write down something custom but I was wondering if there was already something for that. `datetime.timedelta` certainly does not seem to have any specific function to convert from a string.

Comment: Show sample input and output data

Comment: You can use `strptime` to get a `time` or `datetime` object, and construct a `timedelta` using that. The approach depends on your input and what exactly you want to do with it. Check the docs here - https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html